# What is the right way to make an extension method of IEndpointRouteBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I want to make an extension method of IEndpointRouteBuilder (NetCore 3.1), and then make a nuguet package to reused it.

I made an library project, but I changed the .csproj file from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` to have acces to IEndpointRouteBuilder (with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` I got missig reference). I dont know if this is correct; exist a nuget pkg? (NetCore 3.1).

After change the Sdk in the .csproj I added `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>`, but after build the nuget package was not generate.

My question is, How can I make(config) a project to generate a nuget package with an extension method of IEndpointRouteBuilder.

Here my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The csproj file should be like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

you don't need to change *Project Sdk* to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` if you need a package.

The package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing** which contains `IEndpointRouteBuilder`  was removed as part of the 3.0 release. So, to reference the feature, you'll need to add a framework reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`